# slot-contextual-menu is missing in the smartedit with Spartacus integration

Tags: spartacus-storefront

After integration of smartedit with Spartacus, Slot-contextual-menu is missing for the slots, and external-slot-disabled-decorator element is visible in smartedit pages, because of which we are not able to view the slot wrapper around the components.
How can we solve this issue?

Comment: Please check whether file `webApplicationInjector.js` is loaded. This is the Setup Instructions: https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/smartEdit-setup-instructions-for-spartacus/.

Comment: yes webApplicationInjector.js is loaded, editing of components works, but the just the slot-contextual-menu element is missing, instead I see external-slot-disabled-decorator.

Comment: If it is just the slot-contextual-menu element missing, you can contact SmartEdit team. Spartacus only implements the SmartEdit contract. Thanks.

Comment: slot-contextual-menu is missing after integration with Spartacus, with accelerator it works fine

Comment: Is it related to this ticket: https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/845